# How to sample from a sum of two distributions: binomial and poisson

Tags: bayesian, rstan

Is there a way to predict a value from a sum of two distributions? I am getting a syntax error on rstan when I try to estimate y here: y ~ binomial(,) + poisson()

```
library(rstan)

BH_model_block <- "
data{
  int y; 
  int a; 
}

parameters{
  real <lower = 0, upper = 1> c;
  real <lower = 0, upper = 1> b;
}

model{
  y ~ binomial(a,b)+ poisson(c);
}
"
BH_model <- stan_model(model_code = BH_model_block)
BH_fit <- sampling(BH_model,
                   data = list(y = 5,
                               a = 2), 
                   iter= 1000)
```

Produces this error:

```
SYNTAX ERROR, MESSAGE(S) FROM PARSER:

  error in 'model2c6022623d56_457bd7ab767c318c1db686d1edf0b8f6' at line 13, column 20
  -------------------------------------------------
    11: 
    12: model{
    13:   y ~ binomial(a,b)+ poisson(c);
                           ^
    14: }
  -------------------------------------------------

PARSER EXPECTED: ";"
Error in stanc(file = file, model_code = model_code, model_name = model_name,  : 
  failed to parse Stan model '457bd7ab767c318c1db686d1edf0b8f6' due to the above error.
```

Comment: What is the notation `y ~ foo(theta) + bar(phi)` supposed to do in terms of the log density? Are you looking for the distribution of `x + y` where `x ~ binomial(a, b)` and `y ~ poisson(c)`?

Comment: Hi @BobCarpenter, yes, that is right. I am looking for the distribution of x + y where x ~ binomial(a,b) and y ~ poisson(c). When I separate out the terms in the model chunk, I run into an issue where I need to define the new parameter "x" which has to be an integer. It seems like integers cannot be defined in parameter or transformed parameter chunks. I tried defining "int x" in the model chunk but initialization fails (probably because the range for x is not defined?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to substitute the Binomial with a Poisson, and use Poisson additivity:

```
BH_model_block <- "
data{
  int y; 
  int a; 
}

parameters{
  real <lower = 0, upper = 1> c;
  real <lower = 0, upper = 1> b;
}

model{
  y ~ poisson(a * b + c);
}
"
```

This differs in that if `b` is not small, the Binomial has a lower variance than the Poisson, but maybe there is overdispersion anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

Stan doesn't support integer parameters, so you can't technically do that.  For two real variables, it'd look like this:

```
parameters {
  real x;
  real y;
}
transformed parameters {
  real z = x + y;
}
model {
  x ~ normal(0, 1);
  y ~ gamma(0.1, 2);
}
```

Then you get the sum distribution for `z`.   If the variables are discrete, it won't compile.

If you don't need `z` in the model, then you can do this in the generated quantities block,

```
generated quantities {
  int x = binomial_rng(a, b);
  int y = poisson_rng(c);
  int z = x + y;
}
```

The drawback of doing this is that none of the variables are available in the model block.  If you need discrete parameters, they need to be marginalized as described in the user's guide chapter on latent discrete parameters (also in the chapter on mixtures and HMMs).  This is not so easy with a Poisson, because support isn't bounded.  If the expectations of the two discrete distributions is small, then you can do it approximately with a loop over plausible values.

It looked from the example in the original post that `z` is data.  That's a slightly different marginalization over `x` and `y`, but you only sum over the `x` and `y` such that `x + y = z`, so the combinatorics are greatly reduced.